# How have two type of environments in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, environment, xcconfig

I have a project with a 'double' type of environments:

- One for countries(eeuu, eng, fra)
- One for environments(dev,pre,pro)

Which is the best way to implements this in Xcode project?
In projects with only environments, we have a xcconfig files, but, in this case, I don't want have 9 environments files. 
Every combination have a bundle name, icon, urls, ... specific.
I prefer not to duplicate targets if is possible.

In Android it would be done with dimensions and flavors.
I have read multiple tutorials, but none of them explains this.

Comment: if you have different icon & bundle name for each combination there are no other options than having multiple targets

Comment: But with schemes you can have different names and icons (and bundles) of the apps. A simple google search gives you some tutorials for it("different icons xcode schemes")